# How to use ArcPy to Check if Search Cursor Returns Anything

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

How can I use arcpy to check if a search cursor returns anything and then do something based on the answer.  So far I have this and it recognizes the positive - i.e. when i pass the query for 001 it gets the value, but when I substitute a bad value, the script does not print "No Search Cursor"

```
import arcpy

table = "A_Table"
query = "\"FeatureID\" = '001'"  
theseRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table, query)

for row in theseRows:
    if theseRows:
        print(row.getValue("FeatureID"))
    else:
        print "No Search Cursor"
```

Comment: You're trying to do a CountFeatures sort of thing? you should be able to do *if not theseRows:* which will return true if the list (the cursor) is empty.

Comment: if I feed the query a junk value, it is still returning a search cursor object... which tells me I need a method to check and see if the cursor is returning anything at all ,not just that it's been established.

Comment: if not theseRows: should return false if there's nothing in the list but that might be only for arcpy.da.SearchCursor. I always do a count before declaring a cursor as count is lightweight and non-locking but cursors lock (shared) and leave junk that needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An else on a for loop doesn't work like that.

```
for row in theseRows:
    # do interesting work
else:
    print "No rows found"
```

will always print "No rows found" as long as no break was encountered in the for loop.
A For on an empty list is still a non-breaking For.

Something like this would work:

```
flag = False
for row in theseRows:
    flag = True
    # do interesting work

if not flag:
    print "No rows found"
```

Comment: Why does this happen?

Comment: Well just do break and else, or try/catch using cursor.next()

Answer (score 8):

Just a tip - if you're using ArcGIS 10.1 or higher, you should look at the [arcpy.da version of search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000), as it's much faster. Also, consider using the `with...` notation used in the example on that page, as it's a cleaner way to manage the cursor.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

But rather than using a cursor, perhaps a better way to check if the query returns anything is shown in the [Make Query Table example 2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006r000000):

```
# Make Query Table...
arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(tableList, lyrName,"USE_KEY_FIELDS", keyField, fieldList, whereClause)

# Print the total rows
print arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrName)
```

That is, create a query layer from the table and its `where` clause, then use [GetCount](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) to see whether it contains any records.

(PS I just tried @polygeo's suggestion of [MakeTableView](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006v000000) and it's a bit simpler - so you could run that, then GetCount)

Comment: +1 for GetCount but I think the preceding MakeQueryTable step is (often) unnecessary.  If you can open a SearchCursor on it then I think you can usually/always use GetCount.

Comment: @PolyGeo but without making a query table on it, how will you run the query `featureID = 001`? GetCount will return the total count of the table, not just the desired rows

Comment: That's a fair point - MakeFeatureLayer and MakeTableView are two other possible ways that take a where_clause.

Comment: Perhaps though if you insist on skipping the count you could set a boolean before the iteration to false, change to true during iteration and then test afterward - if true then a row has been returned (at least 1) if it's false then no rows were returned... an empty cursor will not enter an iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `else` block on a `for` loop](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html):

```
theseRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table, query)

for row in theseRows:
    # do interesting work
else:
    print "No rows found"
```

Comment: will always print "No rows found" as long as no break was encountered in the for loop. A For on an empty list is still a non-breaking For.

Answer (score 2):

Simple method (used arcpy.da version of cursors in 10.4, works in Pro too)

```
for row in cur:
    break
else:
    print("Cursor is empty")
```

or :

```
try:
    cur.next()
except: #I don't remember the exception but its easy to check
    print("Cursor is empty")
```